# Memory not being cleared fully using delete

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator

I hope this question doesn't get downvoted. I researched a lot before asking this question.
I'm trying to free the memory allocated using the `new` and `delete` operator. After allocating a 1M x 2 matrix, the system monitor showed usage of about 38.2MB of the a.out file. After incorporating the clearMemory() function, the usage shows 30.7 MB.

Here's the function and the main code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//-------------------------Function to clear memory-----------------------------
void clearMemory(int **matrix, int rows)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    delete [] matrix[i];
    matrix[i]   = NULL;
  }

  delete [] matrix;
  matrix = NULL;
  cout<<"\nMemory cleared\n";
}


int main()
{

  int rows=1000000, cols=2;
  int **matrix;
  matrix = new int*[rows];

  for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
  {
    matrix[i] = new int[cols];
    for(int j = 0; j<cols; j++)
    {
      matrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }
  // matrix occupies about 38.2MB in my system.


 clearMemory(matrix, rows);

 while(1){}
 // To pause the program in order to check the system monitor for RAM usage.


 return 0;
}
```

My question is, why isn't the memory fully deallocated? Is there a limit of using the delete operator, because delete works for smaller sized matrices, but for very large matrices like this one, it doesn't seem to be working properly?

**PS**: Please forgive me if this is a trivial question. I really can't seem to find a solution to this problem on my own.

**PPS**: I understand that using vector might be a better practice, but was just curious about new and delete operator on pointers.

Comment: Delete does not immediately return memory to the system for optimization reasons.

Comment: Why do you assign NULL to variables you won't ever read again?

Comment: So If I have to use the same variable for another similar operation, (Example, fill it with 2s instead of 1s) how can I do so without filling up the memory quickly?

Comment: I will probably not fill up. But if you need the exact same, simply use the same one? Allocating and de-allocating is time-consuming.

Comment: BTW your term _clearig memory_ is misleading, it should be _releasing memory_

Comment: The memory after free/delete goes to a pool managed by the program. It's not returned to system immediately, but rather kept in a pool for later reuse. If you then call new, you will be assigned memory from that pool, if there's enough inside, or program will request more from the system. System might demand it's memory back as well, then it will be released. Possibly other scenarios can come. It's implementation specific bahaviour, so hard to give more specific information.

Comment: BTW: as you are using C++ I'd rather use `std::vector` instead of raw pointers.